# ChartJs Not displaying data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm trying to make a graph that displays some Vibration data.
I'm using angular and chartjs.

I declared my labels (512 entries)
I declared my data (512 entries)

and

```
$scope.datasetOverride2 = [{ xAxisID: 'x-axis-1', yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'  }];
$scope.options2 = {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left'
          }
        ],
        xAxes: [{
          id: 'x-axis-1',
          type: 'linear',
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Hz',
            fontStyle: 'bold'
          },
          ticks: {
            min: -1945.4,
            max: 1953,
            callback: function (value, index, values) {
              return parseFloat(value).toFixed(1);
            },
            autoSkip: true
          }
        }]
      }
    };
```

If I remove my xAxes configuration, my graph shows but with the labels I specified.
[image]
Instead, I aim to hide those labels and make the config do the xAxis job by setting the min, max...
Like the following picture, but my data is not being displayed.
[image]
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention when using linear axis configuration, so data are [points](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) identified by a couple `{x, y}` like below:

```
$scope.data = [
    [
        { x: 0, y: 20 }, 
        { x: 1, y: 22 }, 
        { x: 2, y: 30 }, 
        { x: 3, y: 5 }, 
        ...
    ],
```

Check my working example: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/7sbchj9n/